# CBLAS_LAYOUT not declared in gcc version of mkl.h

Tags: c++, gcc, matrix, blas, intel-mkl

I'm trying to compile a large code with gcc(version 5.3) compiler, that was compiled with icpc before.
I have troubles with mkl header files that are not the same in gcc as in intel version.

This is the error I'm getting.

```
error: 'CBLAS_LAYOUT' was not declared in this scope
```

I looked in the include directory of mkl library and its not in any header. This is the piece of code that's throwing the error.

```
#include "simgms_math.h"
#include "mkl_lapacke.h"
#include "mkl.h" 
#include <iostream>
.
.
CBLAS_LAYOUT layout = (rowMajor == 1) ? CblasRowMajor : CblasColMajor;
```

Answer (score 1):

typedef CBLAS_ORDER CBLAS_LAYOUT; /* this for backward compatibility */

Adding the line above fixed the issue, after googling about the issue for a while.